# How can I know that presentation is completed, since there is no semaphores and fences in VkPresentInfoKHR and vkQueuePresentKHR?

Tags: vulkan

I can do synchronizations between acquiring an image from swapchain and rendering, between rendering and presentation, but do I need to wait for presentation completeness before the next loop iteration?

If yes, which sync approach is used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The act of presenting an image is an asynchronous operation that, while is related to a queue, does not complete *because* of queue execution. And it also doesn't/shouldn't hold up that queue, since it may involve CPU operations.

You aren't supposed to wait for presentation to finish, ever. What you want for is for the *acquire* to finish. This is why `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` requires the use of a semaphore/fence. You can't execute commands that manipulate the returned image unless those commands synchronize with the semaphore/fence used to acquire the image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! vkAcquireNextImageKHR holds up the thread execution until image is presented? Is it correct?

Comment: @DenisBelov: I said no such thing. Read the last sentence again.

Comment: I wrote a stupid thing. It seems to be clear now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I like to say this kind of question is invalid.
What do you mean by "presentation is completed"? Presentation **never** completes. The image is presented **indefinitely** and repeatedly until you provide a new one.

Only way to check presentation completed is to call `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`. That tells you presentation engine is done with **only** the image it returns.

But what people asking this usually mean is how to get VSync info. It is currently non-trivial. And it is further investigated how to make it better: [Vulkan-Docs#370](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/370)